# Python Selenium не работает Браузер запускается и все

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, firefox

Выдает ошибку на Chrome

```
[14264:12496:1221/124131.136:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(168)] Failed to launch GPU process.
```

На Firefox тупо не подключается. В обоих случаях браузеры запускаются. На другой машине все работает

```
Message: Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение. (os error 10061)

введите сюда код
```

Да! И мне все это нужно на сервере потом запустить. Это возможно?
windows 10, Python39

Попробовал Iexplorer, запустился, но дико виснет

```
br=webdriver.Ie()   #Chrome(),Firefox()

br.get("https://web.telegram.org/#/login")
```

Вот часть лога geckodriver

```
JavaScript error: chrome://global/content/elements/browser-custom-element.js, line 1270: NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED: Component returned failure code: 0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) [nsIScriptSecurityManager.getLoadContextContentPrincipal]
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/SanityTest.jsm, line 300: TypeError: this.mm is null
[Parent 6668, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: Failed to launch tab subprocess: file z:/task_1579290903/build/src/ipc/glue/GeckoChildProcessHost.cpp, line 681
```

Comment: покажите код и укажите, на чем запускается, на чем нет?

Comment: Я выяснил в чем дело. Драйвер видеокарты не работает. Подскажите как его определить и правильно установить.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел как правильно все запускать без танцев с бубном:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
#options.add_argument(f"--proxy-server=http://{proxy}")
options.add_argument("--window-size-minimize_window")
options.add_argument(f"--user-agent={userAgent}")

br = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
```

Comment: Опции естественно можно выбрать на свое усмотрение, я постарался добавить по максимуму